# Preventing Android development questions being asked

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

Considering questions about Android development are off-topic here, a lot of them are asked! How can we make it really clear when asking a question that it shouldn't be about development and these questions should instead be asked on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Afraid we can't. As hard as we try (and we did in the past), some people first write and then, maybe or not, read (and even if, then not necessarily the hints on what's on-topic). We even have a "development" tag where excerpt and wiki state "OFF-TOPIC!!!" – still we get development questions even using that tag. Afraid not even an electric fence would help with that …

Comment: Damn. Would it be possible to add a filter system that blocks questions with the 'development' tag or that include certain words related to development or would that not be possible because of the Stack Exchange architecture?

Comment: All discussed already. I don't remember everything from what's been discussed – but a search here on Meta might bring it up. Or just check the "Related" section to the right: [Add a note to the “Ask a Question Page” to reinforce that dev questions are off-topic](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/484/16575) / [Put “Dev Qs not allowed” on Ask Question page for new users?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1041/16575) / [How to stop users from posting development questions on Android Enthusiasts?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1239/16575) …

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks for these links. I'll take a look now. I did a search but these didn't come up...

Comment: Yes. I see the issues with this now. Basically everything I thought of has been asked before. Aaah well. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Anytime! Shall we mark this as a duplicate then? Will do so, pointing to the third link (closest match). Thanks for caring! It's really an annoying issue.

Comment: Yep. It is an annoying issue! Thanks again. I've marked this as a duplicate.

Comment: Ah! And learned something else: As soon as OP marks his/her own question "duplicate", our special mod named "Community" swings Tor's hammer and closes it. Nice :)

Comment: @Izzy FYI it's quite [a new feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes) since March 2015 in case you didn't notice it, and yes it's helpful for OP :)